# Java (JSP): repeating the contentType header in a "sub-jsp"

Tags: java, jsp, content-type

What happens when headers are repeated in a .jsp you include in another .jsp?

For example if *example.jsp* starts with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsp:root version="2.0" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<div class="content">

<jsp:include page="support.jsp"/>
...
```

(it includes *support.jsp*)

And then *support.jsp* starts **also** with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsp:root version="2.0" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
...
```

Is that a problem? Is it bad practice?

What does *concretely* happen when you repeat several times a header that only corresponds to one header in the resulting .html page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [JSP Specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr245/index.html):

> JSP.5.4 <jsp:include>
>
> ...
>
> An included page cannot change the
> response status code or set headers.
> This precludes invoking methods like
> setCookie. Attempts to invoke these
> methods will be ignored. The
> constraint is equivalent to the one
> imposed on the include method of the
> RequestDispatcher class.

That is, attempt to set content type will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The directive is translated directly to [ServletResponse.setContentType](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29) call

The documentations for this method says:

> Sets the content type of the response
>   being sent to the client, if the
>   response has not been committed yet.
>   The given content type may include a
>   character encoding specification, for
>   example, text/html;charset=UTF-8. The
>   response's character encoding is only
>   set from the given content type if
>   this method is called before getWriter
>   is called.
>
> This method may be called repeatedly
>   to change content type and character
>   encoding. This method has no effect if
>   called after the response has been
>   committed. It does not set the
>   response's character encoding if it is
>   called after getWriter has been called
>   or after the response has been
>   committed.
>
> Containers must communicate the
>   content type and the character
>   encoding used for the servlet
>   response's writer to the client if the
>   protocol provides a way for doing so.
>   In the case of HTTP, the Content-Type
>   header is used.

It seems to me that it's better to use this directive only once in the top-level JSP page, maybe even in controller servlet, but definitely not in included pages.

For pages not written in JSPX, one directive that **IS** useful and should be set in all JSPs that have non-ascii characters is `<%@ page pageEncoding="XXXX" %>`.  I highly recommend it if you don't like to print \uXXXX codes all over your pages.

Comment: However, the OP is using JSPX (JSP XML, JSP in XML syntax, "JSP document"). The XML declaration already includes the page encoding.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for pointing this out.  Updated language of the last paragraph.  I think the original confusion and proliferation of `contentType` directive stems from not understanding how these 2 totally separate directives work.  Basically if your JSP page does have non-ASCII, it is required to set `pageEncoding`, but you should leave `contentType` to somebody higher in the chain.  At least that was my own confusion.

Comment: I gave you +1 but... You did not really address the question I think: the JLS that axtavt quoted specifically states that *"An included page cannot change the response status code or set headers. Attempts to invoke these methods will be ignored"*.  So AFAICT I'm doing an include and hence the later calls are going to be ignored.  This is not the same as what you quoted, which deals specifically with the *setContentType* method (apparently when *not* called from inside an "included" .jsp).

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely normal practice.

What you call 'headers' are just directives to jsp-compiler.

Comment: +1 but what I call "header" is also called a "header" in the official JSP specification quoted by axtavt ;)