# Compilation Error on jsp content type

Tags: jsp, character-encoding, content-type, jsp-tags, jspinclude

I have two jsps , where  main.jsp includes sub.jsp

The content type of main.jsp is set as `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>`

Where as that of the sub.jsp as `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>`

(Note the space in content type)

The main.jsp includes sub.jsp using the below include tag

```
 <%@ include file="/jsp/sub.jsp" %>
```

On including a file repeating the content type has no effect!
But still on compilation

> llegal to have multiple occurrences of contentType with different values (old: text/html;charset=UTF-8, new: text/html; charset=UTF-8)

Confused ! 
Does a "space" makes it a different content type? 
What happens with content type during compilation? Is it taken as two different content types ?
Why do I get this exception!

Comment: i think you should not have two content type in one jsp. remove content type and charset from sub.jsp. it should work.

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743585/error-illegal-to-have-multiple-occurrences-of-contenttype-with-different-val

Comment: Does Repeating the content type in a included jsp has any effect ?check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898991/java-jsp-repeating-the-contenttype-header-in-a-sub-jsp it says no effect!